# Google Analytics Goal Source

Tags: google-analytics

I have a goal which detects if someone made a purchase on my website. I want to know where that person came from (adwords, facebook, organic, etc).

The problem is that Analytics tells me the source of all these people is the payment processor. This isn't surprising as the flow looks as follows:

Checkout Page -> Paypal.com -> Payment Success Page

It tells me all my goals came from paypal. I want to know where these people came from originally. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to add the payment processor to the referral exclusion list in the property settings. If you do that it will be ignored as a traffic source and the original channel information will be retained. It will also affect the number of sessions - a change in traffic attribution starts a new sessions, so after the change you should expect somewhat fewer sessions with more pageviews.

Unfortunately the setting is not applied retroactively, so traffic data up until you implement the setting is lost for good.